# How to set up a buffer to receive command output

Tags: neovim, job-control

In my `$VIMRC`, I would like to

```
autocmd BufWinEnter *.ly call s:BufWinEnterLY()
autocmd TextChanged *.ly call s:TextChangedLY()
autocmd BufUnload *.ly call s:BufUnloadLY()
```

I want `s:BufWinEnterLY()` to create a buffer below with the intent to act as a log that cannot be modified, which I will explain further down.

I want `s:TextChangedLog()` to execute asynchronously `lilypond "some predefined arguments"` and have all stderr output from that be appended to the aforementioned log.

I want `s:BufUnloadLY()` to simply delete the log buffer.

I have tried using jobstart with `rpc` = true, `termopen` then `rpcnotify`, `serverstart` + `sockconnect` then `rpcnotify`, but none of these methods work. Any help?

Comment: that looks more like 3 separate questions. It should be possible to have a buffer receive the stderr of some jobs, please show what your current function looks like.

Comment: I agree with @ChristianBrabandt .For example to answer the question on the title I would say execute the command with a `.` in front (e.g. try opening vim and type `:.!date`) but that doesn't relate at all with your actual question

Comment: I don’t think you need rpc here—just to direct the output streams to the buffer. If there isn’t already an option to do this, you could write a callback, or just use `:terminal ++shell lilypond args >/dev/null` (I’m assuming you only care about stdout)